# socket.isConnected() does not detect disconnected socket

Tags: java, sockets

I have a Java application that connects to a service using a socket. I always expect to receive something from that socket, and if it disconnects I need to reconnect. Reconnect works fine when I close/open socket from remote application side in normal way. But when the remote application is killed, my Java application does not detect that. I run the thread with:

```
if (socket.isConnected()) { /* code */ }
```

This function does not detect when the socket is killed. Why? How to detect that remote socket is killed?

**Note:** I must use java 1.4

UPD

I do reading from socket input stream acording loggic:

```
 if (in.available()) {...}
```

This not detects socket is disconnected. Should I use `in.read()` even if no data available to detect closed socket?

Comment: *Closing a socket doesn't clear its connection state, which means this method will return true for a closed socket (see `isClosed()`) if it was successfuly connected prior to being closed.* - from [Socket#isConnected Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#isConnected%28%29)

Answer (score 6):

The various `isXXX()` methods of `Socket` don't track the actual state, but what has been done to the socket. For example `isConnected()` will return true even after a socket has been closed, if it has been connected at some point.

The **only** way to detect if a `Socket` is still valid is to try to use it, i.e. read or write to it. If an exception is thrown, you need to clean up and reconnect.

Comment: Read is simpler than send something. Message body UPD contains my read from socket experience. How I can read something if nothing is available on socket?

Comment: I didn't specify that you should use either one. I just said that the **only** way is to **use** the socket, i.e. read **or** write from/to it.

Answer (score 2):

> This function does not detect when the socket is killed. Why?

These functions only tell you the current state of the `Socket` object: they don't actively test the line. `isConnected()` means 'have I ever connected?'.

> How to detect that remote socket is killed?

You need to read a message from the connection with an appropriate timeout. If the connection is closed or lost you eventually get an IOException, or a timeout will be reached.

BTW To save error messages, I suggest you send a message indicating a graceful disconnect before closing.  This way graceful disconnects can be treated differently to connection failures in term of logging.

Comment: how to send graceful disconnect? Is it standard socket function?

Comment: @vico you need to add your own protocol to send messages over TCP.  You can add a message which is a poison pill which causes the other end to close the connection gracefully. This way the other end knows if the close was deliberate (and possibly handled silently) or unexpectedly.

Comment: @vico Close the socket, or shut it down for output.